# NotImplementedError: PostCreateView is missing the implementation of the test_func() method

Tags: django

Please help me solve this bug Iam in learning stage in django and here's my code:
views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.
 
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Post.objects.all
    }
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context)
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    # <app>/<model><viewtype>.html
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    #LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin,DeleteView
    #LoginRequiredMixin, AuthorMixin, ListView
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def about(request):
    return render(request,'blog/about.html',{'title':'About'})
```

error : NotImplementedError: PostCreateView is missing the implementation of the test_func() method.
Iam learning to code in django and Iam facing frequent bugs please help me Iam trying to do this with my full energy and Iam a self taught coder so I have no one to ask my questions or clear my doubts.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `UserPassesTestMixin` in `PostCreateView`? If there is nothing to test, just remove that from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `PostCreateView`, you're inheriting from `UserPassesTestMixin` which requires you to override the `test_func` in your class, as indicated in [the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin.test_func)